# Changing Color of Author Thanks in Document

Tags: formatting, titles

Let's say you have the following title in `mwe.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Sample Title}
\author{John Doe\thanks{email}~ and Jane Doe\thanks{twitter}}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

Here's the output:

[image: result of mwe.tex]

How would I go about changing the color of the symbols used to represent the `\thanks` in the title (the * and the cross)? I tried using the `hyperref` package to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that only for the typesetting of `\maketitle` command `\thanks` is defined as copy of `\footnote`.

So we have to patch command `\maketitle` and add there the for example color `red` for the footnote mark in the title like:

```
\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\patchcmd{\maketitle}%
  {\def\@makefnmark{\rlap{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}}%
  {\def\@makefnmark{\rlap{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\color{red}\@thefnmark}}}}% <==================
  {}%success
  {}%failure
\makeatother % <========================================================
```

Commands `makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are only needed because `@` is used in the code to be patched. With the complete mwe

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % <===============================================

\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\patchcmd{\maketitle}%
  {\def\@makefnmark{\rlap{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}}%
  {\def\@makefnmark{\rlap{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\color{red}\@thefnmark}}}}%
  {}%success
  {}%failure
\makeatother % <========================================================

\title{Sample Title}
\author{John Doe\thanks{email}~ and Jane Doe\thanks{twitter}}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

Blah blah blah\footnote{This is a test.}

\end{document}
```

you get the resulting pdf:

[image: resulting title]

Comment: Awesome! However, when I use the ```hyperref``` package *before* your setup, the colors do not change, but when I use it *after*, it works fine. Do you know why this happens (it does not affect your answer in any way)?